# Angular interpolates within a directive template and sometimes not?

Tags: angularjs

I have this template stored in a file which is pointed to by a templateUrl in a custom directive called budgetRow:

```
<tr class="item_row" id="{{rowId}}">
  <td class="item_cell" id="description">
    <input type="text" ng-model='budget.row({{rowId}}).description' >
  </td>
</tr>
```

When $scope.rowId is set to 10, this is what get rendered in the browser.

```
<budget-row>
  <tr class="item_row" id="10">
    <td class="item_cell" id="description">
        <input type="text" ng-model="budget.row({{rowId}}).description"
               class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    </td>
  </tr>
</budget-row>
```

Why does "{{rowId}}" get interpolated in the tr element but not in the td element?

Comment: Is `budget.row` a function that returns an object? Or are you trying to pass dynamic property name variable for object? Either way you don't use interpolation

Comment: Beware of putting elements such as `<budget-row>` as parent of a `<tr>` element. Some browsers will automatically self-close the element and ignore the `</budget-row>` closing tag.

Comment: Not sure I understand this comment.  What do you mean by "elements such as <budget-row>  Do you mean tags that are Angular directives or someting else?  The tr is part of a budget-row template from Angular.  So I shouldn't include tr inside of my templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the interpolation from the `ng-model` directive:

```
<tr class="item_row" id="{{rowId}}">
  <td class="item_cell" id="description">
    ̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶t̶e̶x̶t̶"̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶'̶b̶u̶d̶g̶e̶t̶.̶r̶o̶w̶(̶{̶{̶r̶o̶w̶I̶d̶}̶}̶)̶.̶d̶e̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶'̶ ̶>̶
    <input type="text" ng-model='budget.row(rowId).description' >
  </td>
</tr>
```

The `ng-model` directive take an AngularJS expression. There is no need to do interpolation in an AngularJS expression.

The `id` attribute is not an AngularJS directive. It is vanilla HTML, thus to inject an AngularJS expression use interpolation.

From the Docs:

> ### Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-).